# Selecting a length of time with numericUpDowns and windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building an auto clicker application that makes the mouse click at a set interval of time.

[image]

Notice the interval configuration area. I have tried to write some logic that automatically simplifies the amount of time entered. The minutes box goes up to 60, the seconds box goes up to 60, and the milliseconds box goes up to 1000. I have a class set up to handle that logic, but it's probably not the right way to do that (I'm still new at programming).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoClicker {
    public static class TotalTime {
        public static int Interval(NumericUpDown m_, NumericUpDown s_, NumericUpDown ms_) {
            int m = (int)m_.Value;
            int s = (int)s_.Value;
            int ms = (int)ms_.Value;
            int total = 0;

            total = total + (m * 60000);
            total = total + (s * 1000);
            total = total + ms;

            return total;
        }

        public static void ChangeLogic(NumericUpDown m_, NumericUpDown s_, NumericUpDown ms_) {
            int interval = Interval(m_, s_, ms_);

            if (ms_.Value == 1000)
            {
                ms_.Value = 500;
                s_.UpButton();
                ms_.Value = 0;
            }

            if (s_.Value == 60 && m_.Value < 60)
            {
                if (ms_.Value == 0)
                {
                    ms_.Value = 1;
                    s_.Value = 0;
                    m_.UpButton();
                    ms_.Value = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    s_.Value = 0;
                    m_.UpButton();
                    if (ms_.Value == 1)
                        ms_.DownButton();
                }
            }

            if (ms_.Value == -1)
            {
                ms_.Value = 999;
                s_.DownButton();
            }

            if (s_.Value == -1 & m_.Value > 0)
            {
                s_.Value = 59;
                m_.DownButton();
                if (ms_.Value == 1)
                    ms_.DownButton();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ChangeLogic method is called each time the value in any of the boxes is updated.

There's lots of bugs in the selection logic. For example, when the up button for seconds is held down, the program crashes. If seconds = 59 and minutes = 0, and the seconds up button is pressed, the warning "you can't have a time less than 250 milliseconds" shows up and minutes is adjusted to 2.

I'm really confused. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Self-inflicted wound, the UI is too clumsy.  Use a *single* NUD to set the value and radio buttons to select the unit.

Comment: I can try that, but I'd really like the UI to stay the same.

Comment: The idea proposed by @HansPassant will probably work well for you. Also: knowing how to use [breakpoints](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSBreakpoints.aspx) might help a lot, if you don't know already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like your intent is to have it so that when you up the milliseconds it then rolls up to the seconds once it hits 1000, then when your seconds hit 60 it rolls up to your minutes, etc etc.

Here is how I would accomplish this.  First set all of your NUDs to max value of 99999.  Then use code that looks something like this:

(Note the use of the `intervalUpdating` variable.  This will make it so that you can hold that up button and while the `intervalChanged()` method is executing it wont try to execute it again.)

```
    private void nudSeconds_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        intervalChanged();
    }

    private void nudMilliseconds_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        intervalChanged();
    }

    private bool intervalUpdating = false;
    private void intervalChanged()
    {
        if (intervalUpdating)
        {
            return;
        }

        intervalUpdating = true;

        if (nudMilliseconds.Value >= 1000)
        {
            var val = (int)nudMilliseconds.Value / 1000;
            nudSeconds.Value += val;
            nudMilliseconds.Value = (nudMilliseconds.Value - (val * 1000));
        }

        if (nudSeconds.Value >= 60)
        {
            var val = (int)nudSeconds.Value / 60;
            nudMinutes.Value += val;
            nudSeconds.Value = (nudSeconds.Value - (val * 60));
        }

        intervalUpdating = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks much. I've added this code, and I've also added logic for removing values. Does this look alright?

http://pastebin.com/NbYVCske (too long for comment)

Comment: yep, looks great to me.  let me know if you have any other questions about it.